# Calculated Column formula returns syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

Found this one that seems to be the solution needed but i cant get it to work:

Column1 has the value of BD122

**Formula:**
`=EXACT([Column1], "BD122")`

**Expected result:**
Compares contents of Column1 and the string "BD122" 
Should Return value (Yes) in my calculated Column2

Running On-Premise Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise
ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Comment: It works. What is the error message?

Comment: I'm also getting it to work. Maybe this is a missing parenthesis, comma, or quote? Fire up the ULS viewer and see what the correlated error is saying.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helps to use an excel spreadsheet when dealing with formulas for calculated columns.